# SwiftUI: Using a ForEach to dynamically load Images

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a handful of images with names such as `area`, `volume`, etc.

I want to use data to drive the images displayed. This is an example of what `places` can be:

```
   let places = {
      names: ["area", "volume"]
   }
```

I tried something like this below but getting `Referencing initializer 'init(_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'String' conform to 'Identifiable'`

```
    ForEach(places.name) { place in
        NavigationLink (destination: Any()) {
            HStack {
                Image(place)

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For types like `String` that don't directly conform to `Identifiable`, you can tell the `ForEach` what property to use as an `id`. Often with `String`, you'll want to use `.self` (note this can yield funny results if the `String`s are not unique).

```
struct Places {
    var names : [String]
}

struct ContentView : View {
    let places : Places = Places(names: ["area", "volume"])
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(places.names, id:\.self) { place in
                NavigationLink (destination: Text("Detail")) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(place)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```